# How to launch web project with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#

I tried to launch a C# web project from Visual Studio 2017 emulator and it doesn't work:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

I'm using IIS and I'm not in `wwwroot`.

I already tried to activate in IIS but it's not what I want.

Any advice?

Comment: What is "Visual Studio 2017 emulator"?

Comment: What emulator? You should be able to debug a VS project with F5 and it will start an internal instance of IIS to display the web page. Sounds like you have something mixed up there. You don't need to have IIS installed on your computer to run the project. But if you want to deploy your web page to IIS you have to properly configure it and Deploy the project.

Answer (score 0):

403.14 - Forbidden "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory." is related to the directory your application is running in.

This problem might occur as you don't have neither Directory Browsing feature enabled nor you have configured a default document.

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
       <files>
          <add value="your index file here" />
       </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

or

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

[This page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942062/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage) shows you the way how to configure one of the two features mentioned.